# Make element draggable on mousedown event of its own implicitely

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hello I am trying with following code to make clicked element draggable at runtime, but its not working for any element for its very first click after first click its working fine, I dont know why it happen,Please help me out.
Mine code is as follows:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(document).mousedown(function(event) {
        $("#"+$(event.target).attr("id")).draggable();
        console.log($(event.target).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.draggable` call is in the `mousedown` handler - that way it is initialized on the first click. You might initialize it in the `$(document).ready` handler instead to make it work on first click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("div.dragMe").draggable();
    $(document).mousedown(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

In this code, all `div`s having the `class="dragMe"` would be made draggable.

Comment: actually at runtime want to make clicked element draggable, id or class of checked element wouldn't be known to us ....if that would be condition then??

Comment: sorry not checked its clicked

Comment: Not sure if I understand your comment right. You must know a selector for the elements to make them draggable. They are somehow added to the DOM - I assume you know the elements when adding them. If you have any questions regarding that, please add a new question and include the relevant code where you add the items.

Comment: Please do not forget to mark this as "answered" using the green check mark on the left (@see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: but buddy u didn't solve the problem that i wanted to solve

Comment: Didn`t that help to solve the items being draggable on second click only? Whatever...